# Skip first mvn install in travis-ci

Tags: travis-ci

I'm having troubles building a project with maven on travis-ci because travis automatically runs

```
mvn install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V
```

which fails because of a timeout:

```
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially
indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself
```

According to the documentation I should be able to override it defining a custom script in `.travis.yml` but it does not work, here my configuration:

```
  sudo: false
  language:
    - java
  script: "travis_wait mvn -T4 -pl quickfixj-codegenerator install"
  jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
  env:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx=2048m"
  branches:
    only:
      - travis-ci-build
```

Is there any way to avoid the automatic mvn install or to tweak it ?

Answer (score 12):

This is mentioned in the documentation:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#skipping-the-installation-phase

> Skip the installation step entirely by adding the following to your `.travis.yml`:

```yaml
install: skip
```

The `install` step runs before `script` step, and with Maven you don't usually need the `install` step, at least I personally haven't ever found it useful — Maven will download dependencies on `script` step anyway.

Comment: This is true but it does not solve the problem as the mavenrc settings override any memory settings you may set with env so the build will fail so you need to skip install and use custom script to set proper environment

Comment: Instead of executing `true`, I like to execute `echo Skipping install step`, which achieves the same thing, but also prints an informative message.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. It was solved after some discussion with the Travis CI support. Here is their response:

> That maven command is run as part of the install section of your
>   build, it's the default.
>
> If you want to skip this step, you can override it by adding this to
>   your `.travis.yml` file:
>
> `install: /bin/true`

Comment: The main problem is that maven loads /etc/mavenrc which sets min/max memory and this cause problem if your build require custom settings. I've ended up writing with [this](https://github.com/lburgazzoli/quickfixj/blob/travis-ci-build/.travis.yml)

Answer (score 8):

I have found it useful to have an `install: mvn dependency:resolve` step that downloads the build dependencies up front, so that the output of the actual build script is kept clean